# fail2ban <HOST> regex alias explanation

Tags: regex

I've set up fail2ban to protect a host, and I've noticed this piece of information

```
#_daemon = asterisk                                                                            

# Option:  failregex                                                                   
# Notes.:  regex to match the password failures messages in the logfile. The           
#          host must be matched by a group named "host". The tag "<HOST>:.*" can       
#          be used for standard IP/hostname matching and is only an alias for          
#          (?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>\S+)                                                  
# Values:  TEXT
```

How does the `(?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>\S+)` regex work? I've been trying it in a few different regex checkers and explainers and none could parse it, at least the `(?P<host>\S+)` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?P<name>regex)`
Captures the text matched by "regex" into the group "name". The name can contain letters and numbers but must start with a letter.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html

```
(?:::f{4,6}:)?(?P<host>\S+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qPyc41ABev5byIES)

Answer (score 3):

It can match strings like `::ffff:The_Host`, but the `::ffff:` part is optional. The part `The_Host` part is captured to a capture group called *host*.

If there are more than 6 f letters, the whole thing becomes the host!

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/3), you can see some matches. In the right pane, you can see the capture groups for each match.